# Sharing visual studio macros with team members

Tags: visual-studio, macros

Is it possible to add visual studio macros to a solution, so they would be checked in by svn ?

If not, how do you deploy your utilities/scripts with your developer team ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, VS Macros are stored in a .vsmacros file as selected when you created the Macro project (I think the default location is `C:\Users\yourname\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VSMacros80`), so just copy that file to your project's directory and add it to the project with no build action and you should be all set.

But that's just if you want to use those macros only with that project, most macros are useful in many projects and if so I'd recommend keeping them where they are rather than in the folder of just one project, and then just add the .vsmacros file manually to subversion to some suitable location (suggestion would be a `Tools` folder) and check in and out manually when needed.